# Много подлключений к одному серверу - C#

Tags: c#, сокет

Добрый вечер всем,мне нужно реализовать сервер, и чтобы к нему могло подключится много клиентов, как такое реализовать? Работаю с классом Socket, я делал подобное но только 1 подключение, 1 сервер = 1 клиент, а хотеось бы 1 сервер = 100 клиентов(примерно)

Answer (score 2):

На каком уровне возник вопрос? В целом в простейшем случае можно создавать по одному обслуживающему потоку на одно входящее подключение. Для чего-то высоконагруженного есть смысл использовать пары методов [BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx)/[EndAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept.aspx) в потоке, который принимает входящие подключения, и BeginReceive/EndReceive в обслуживающем потоке.

Общий принцип остается прежним: после подключения первого клиента продолжаете слушать входящие подключения параллельно с первым.

Comment: Просто когда я подобную задачу решал на VB 6.0 там было проще, массив из сокетов, и потом по номеру массива можно было к каждому обратится, а вот в C# трудновато как-то.

Comment: А что конкретно мешает перейти от модели с одним клиентом к модели со множественными клиентами?

Comment: Не знаю, я попробовал сделать такое-же в C#

    Socket[] sck = new Socket[10];

И потом обращаться к каждому элементу массива, но он ругается что типо не указана ссылка на объект.

А что за модель?

Comment: Конечно, ведь вам нужно инициализировать каждый элемент массива так же, как первоначально вы инициализировали единственный сокет.

Comment: И как быть в такой ситуации? Можете дать пример кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: Примеров, вообще говоря, большое количество, на любой вкус и цвет. Например, http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server